# Bazaar error when branching a Launchpad repo

Tags: launchpad, bazaar

I tried to install Ubuntu TV in Ubuntu 12.04 by following [this guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuTV/Contributing).

Everything had been OK until I executed in the terminal `bzr branch lp:~s-team/ubuntutv/trunk ubuntu-tv`. I get the following error message:

> Permission denied (publickey). ConnectionReset reading response for
>   'BzrDir.open_2.1', retrying Permission denied (publickey). bzr: ERROR:
>   Connection closed: Unexpected end of message. Please check
>   connectivity and permissions, and report a bug if problems persist.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you have problems with your bzr configurations. I used to have these problems because of a network firewall and I just have to do away with my bzr configurations.

You can try these steps and see if it works:

```
mv .bazaar .bazaar.backup/
```

Doing that would give you a fresh configuration settings for bzr and you can try branching the ubuntu-tv again.

```
bzr branch lp:~s-team/ubuntutv/trunk ubuntu-tv
```

Comment: Thank you! But now, when I run the same command, I get this:

Permission denied (publickey).
ConnectionReset reading response for 'BzrDir.open_2.1', retrying
Permission denied (publickey).
bzr: ERROR: Connection closed: Unexpected end of message. Please check connectivity and permissions, and report a bug if problems persist.

Comment: @AleksiKinnunen Are you sure you ran the first command? If you did, you wouldn't get any error. If you still do, check if you have network firewall.

Comment: I downloaded gufw firewall manager, but firewall is disabled. I've run everything needed.

Comment: This solution doesn't help if after `mv .bazaar .bazaar.backup/` you also do `bzr launchpad-login myusername`. To solve the issue in the OP, you need to make sure that you have a valid SSH key (both locally and on Launchpad). See [other answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/117576/bazaar-error-when-branching-a-launchpad-repo/117973#117973).

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have trouble connecting to Launchpad over SSH. Make sure that you have a public SSH key registered on Launchpad for which you have the private key available locally, and check that Launchpad knows about your username (`bzr lp-login <username>`).

To [create an SSH key](https://help.launchpad.net/YourAccount/CreatingAnSSHKeyPair) you can:

```
ssh-keygen
```

Then you can easily [upload your SSH public key to Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~/+editsshkeys) (usually `~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub` or `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`).

Alternatively, since you're only trying to access a public branch (which doesn't require authentication) you can also simply force bzr to use http by running `bzr config --remove launchpad_username`.

Comment: You certainly don't need to register on launchpad to branch projects. Yes Bazaar will give you a warning that you won't be able to write to launchpad, but that doesn't prevent you from branching or checkout.

Comment: This is indeed the issue that has been plaguing me. It's not sufficient to set up your GPG keys for Launchpad; you also have to set up the SSH keys! Especially if you have already instructed Launchpad about your username via `bzr launchpad-login myusername`. Or if you want to commit.

Answer (score 1):

It seems Launchpad is unreachable from your PC.

If you have a proxy server in your network, you need to set the `https_proxy` environment variable in the format `http://[user[:pass]@]server[:port]/[path]`, for example:

```
https_proxy=http://jack:badpass@our.intranet.com:8080/proxy.js
```

What is your output to this command:

```
bzr resolve lp:~s-team/ubuntutv/trunk ubuntu-tv
```

And to this one:

```
python -c "import socket; socket.gethostbyname('code.launchpad.net')
```

And this one:

```
env | grep https_proxy
```